# asin, arcsin, $\sin^{-1}$ - is there any convention?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, convention, trigonometry

I've seen multiple forms how the arc sine is marked. But is there any convention which form is mostly being used? Does this depend on the country?

Comment: Yes, there are at least three conventions. `;-)` Not much more to say, I'm afraid.

Comment: This would seem to be a good question for the [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) sister site.